# ScyllaDB Not getting Installed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt

I have tried the steps on the website of ScyllaDB - http://www.scylladb.com/doc/getting-started-ubuntu16.04/
Also, I have went through this step of deb installation - http://www.scylladb.com/download/#fndtn-deb
But I didn't got anything. I want to install scylla, but not able to.
Whenever I try to install using - `sudo apt-get install scylla` I get errors where it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package scylla
```

Please if anyone has any information why it is happening then do let me know. I have even gone through the other related questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I got my mistake. I have added the repository and was instantly trying to install scylla. I forgot to update the repository.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally it worked...:)